# OnBootComplete Dagger 2 doesnt work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, dagger-2

Hi i have the below broadcast reciever that retrieves a onboot complete to do some stuff but it fails  saying no injector factory bound found for the reciever.

my guess is that dagger cant be initialised without the app launching manually by a user?

```
class BootReceiver : DaggerBroadcastReceiver(){

    @Inject
    lateinit var storageClearSchedular: StorageClearSchedularContract

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        Log.d(BootReceiver::class.java.simpleName,"Starting up schedulers for clearing cache")
        storageClearSchedular.setAllSchedulars()
    }
}
```

error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

Comment: Hi is this public class? don't forget to add public keyword

Comment: yes by default kotlin classes are publuc

Comment: Yup you right..

Comment: Hi can you post DaggerBroadcastReceiver  class code and have you written dagger injection codes?

Comment: That is a Dagger class from there library

Comment: ok understand, thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's no injector factory bound for your BroadcastReceiver because there's no component providing it. First you need to create a new module e.g. `ReceiversBindingModule`:

```
@Module
interface ReceiversBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    fun provideBootReceiver(): BootReceiver
}
```

Then you need to add it to your `AppComponent`

```
@Component(modules = [
    ...
    ReceiversBindingModule::class,
    ...])
class AppComponent
```